# How to include external .js file to ejs Node template page

Tags: node.js, ejs

I cannot find a way to include external .js file to Node ejs template. I want to put logic and data into object in external .js file, include that file to index.ejs template and pull data from it.

I tried by inserting standard way
`<script src="sample.js"></script>`, and it doesn't work

Then I tried ejs specific keyword `<% include partials/sample.js %>` and this works only for adding partials (ejs code snippets).

I inserted .js file into static directory which is defined in executable server.js, no results again.

But interestingly, including css file into ejs template classic way works fine, for example

```
<link href="/assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Workaround would be to include external ejs file where I would put logic and data inside <% %> tags, but this is obviously a patch and not a viable solution, because ejs is not a js file. Besides, it doesn't work.

I cannot find any solution on Internet. Any hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You can't**.

Note: You can only pass data from .ejs file to .js file but not the other way. It won't work because .ejs is rendered on the server side while .js runs on the client side. 
I am assuming you are using EJS on server side

1) You can pass an ejs variable value to a Javascript variable

```
    <% var test = 101; %> // variable created by ejs
    <script>
       var getTest = <%= test  %>;  //var test is now assigned to getTest which will only work on browsers
       console.log(getTest);  // successfully prints 101 on browser
    </script>
```

2) You can't pass a js variable value to a ejs variable

Yes, you can't: **if it is on server.**

Why:

The EJS template will be rendered on the server before the js is started execution(it will start on browser), so there is no way going back to server and ask for some previous changes on the page which is already sent to the browser.

Comment: Thanks but somehow it doesn't work for me. It says 'Reference error, data is not defined' ... where in my .js file i have var data = {name: 'Peter'};

Comment: I got it. You cannot have two way transaction between your .js file and .ejs file. Because ejs file will be rendered on the server side and js file will be rendered on the client side. You can pass data from ejs to js but not from js back to ejs **(which you are trying to do)**. Please mark the answer as verified so it will be useful for others.

Comment: Thanks @Bharathvaj for your kind effort. So how can we then import data to a template like EJS. Standard html way we would enclose a link to .js file from where we would import data, make database query etc. Or we would do it inside <script> tags. How then to bring data to .ejs template so that we can display it there. If we try to build data logic inside routes file, for example inside server.js ..  app.get(/someroute), there would be too much code inside each route. Isn't there a more elegant way for importing data to ejs, vue and other templates.

Comment: Server side rendering is mainly used to secure data... which means in client side everything it open to the world so instead of sending the actual data developers used to send the html templates with data in place

Answer (score 5):

A workaround with Express:

myScripts.js

```
module.export = {
    foo() {},
    bar() {}
}
```

Then in your app.js

```
var myScripts = require('/path/to/myScripts');

res.render('template', {
    utils: myScripts
}); // you forgot a ')' here
```

then in your template.ejs

```
// utils will act in global scope for this file
<%
  utils.foo();
  utils.bar();
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are using it contrary to the intent.
In a controller you can define external scripts and styles you want to include like so

```
      res.render('page-one', {
        title: 'Page One',
        data: pageData,
        libs: ['page-one', 'utils'],
        styles: ['page-one']
      });
```

In your static assets for your app you have a js folder and a css folder

```
            |- static/
               |- css/
               |- fonts/
               |- img/
               |- js/
               favicon.ico
            |- templates/
```

In your js folder you place the file page-one.js and utils.js
In your css folder you place the file page-one.css

In the head section of your html in the ejs template

```
    <!-- styles included on all pages -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
    <!-- styles specific to individual pages -->
    <% if (typeof styles !== 'undefined') { %>
        <% if (styles.length > 0) { %>
            <% for (let style of styles) { %>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/<%= style %>.css">
            <% } %>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
```

Typically it is best practice to include scripts at closing body tag so they don't block page render so before the closing body tag in your ejs file

```
<!-- scripts included on all pages -->
<script src='/js/libs/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<!-- page specific scripts -->
<% if (typeof libs !== 'undefined') { %>
    <% for (let lib of libs) { %>
        <script src='/js/<%= lib %>.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
</body>
```

When your page renders it will render the script and CSS includes automatically
The if block is in case you don't define any includes in the controller.
In your Express application you define your static and external script includes like so
Remember up above we created js and css folders inside a directory named static

```
// Define static assets
app.use(express.static('static'));
// included on all pages
app.use('/js/libs', express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules/jquery/dist'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
```

Finally, if you absolutely must include JavaScript in your template like rendering  JSON data, etc. using special ejs tag <%- %>

```
<% if (jsonData) { %>
<script id="jsonData">var jsonData=<%- JSON.stringify(jsonData) %>;</script>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do that by:

1. serving the Js folder/file in the node app entry file like so:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views/js')));
```

2. Added DOM functions in a index.js file which is in views/js folder.
3. Added script tag that links to the index.js file before the end body tag of index.ejs file like so:

```
<script scr="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Note that the src in the script tag does not have `"./js/index.js"`. I actually don't know why it works that way (same with external css stylesheet).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by adding the code below:
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,public)));`

You have to add a directory named public (or whatever you are naming) in your project folder. In that folder you can add your external JS file.

NB: the expression `path.join` is used to make the directory public available/accessible when you call/initiate app from outside the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually achieve that (more specifically for DOM):
1)
set your static assets (server side)

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

2)create for example a folder named js inside your public folder

3)put whatever js file you need to include in your ejs file inside this folder (public/js/external.js)

4)finally put in the end/beginning (you can use defer in your tag depends on the need of preloading or postloading) of your ejs file

```
<script src='/js/external.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

(if you try to access this path automatically in vscode you will find nothing because it was already changed by the app on the server side so it knows all static assets are automatically pulled from there)