# Write ejs variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

I am appending some html to a `div` using jQuery:

**public/js/writeInputs.js**

```
$("#myDiv").append("<input type='search' value='<%= filters.title %>' name='filters[title]' class='form-control'>")
```

In this case `filters` is an object that I'm passing from my node express backend, the value of which I want to display in my input. However, the above renders the `ejs` variable as the string literal:

```
<%= filters.title %>
```

If I hardcode this value into the html it works as expected:

**views/partials/inputs.ejs**

```
<input type="search" name="filters[title]" value="<%= filters.title %>" class="form-control">
```

How can I write an ejs variable in jQuery?

I've tried these approaches in my append, but none work:

```
value="<%= filters.title %>"
value=${<%= filters.title %>}
value='"<%= filters.title %>"'
```

Comment: Your code is in a ejs file or a regular js file?

Comment: The `append` happens in a `js` file, but the element that it appears on is an `ejs` template

Comment: did you remember to make sure that `writeInputs.js` _does not get served as static asset from your public dir_ but instead has its own GET routing function so that your server can load in the file and respond using `respond.render(...)`?

Comment: have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47009932/7353745). You can declare the variable in the browser with the ejs value and it'll be available for jquery.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - Thanks for the comment but I'm not sure that I follow

Comment: you're using a server to render pages using `ejs` syntax. Any file with ejs syntax needs to be served that way, they cannot just be put in the static/public dir and loaded directly from that file by the user. The URL request for `writeInputs.js` needs to go to an actual serving route (like `app.get('writeInputs.js', ...)` if you're using express) and you _have_ to use ejs rendering if you want your ejs syntax to get replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node express first renders HTML and then browser do some requests based on HTML to get scripts, images, etc. For this reason `<%= filters.title %>` is not interpreted by EJS.

As an alternative render some data into HTML and rewrite JavaScript to read `filters.title` from HTML, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="filter" value="<%= filters.title %>" />

<script src="yourScript.js"></script>
```

**yourScript.js**:

```
    var filter = document.getElementById("filter").value;
    $("#myDiv").append("<input type='search' value='" + filter + "' name='filters[title]' class='form-control'>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Only ejs files inside your views folder are rendered from the server so you will have to create the variable in that file instead. Here is an example:

**view.ejs**

```
<script>
    var ejsVal = <%= val %>; // You have to use var to make it global
</script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

**script.js**

```
console.log(ejsVal);
```

Comment: You have to write your ejs syntax inside QUOTES like, "<%=  val %>"

Answer (score 0):

can you try like this?

```
var temp = <%= test  %>;
$("#myDiv").append("<input type='search' value='"+temp+"' name='filters[title]' class='form-control'>");
```

Comment: Thanks but it still gets rendered as a string literal: `"<%= filters.title %>"`

Comment: @fugu changed can you try this

Comment: But `<%= test  %>` won't be available in my `.js` file

Comment: Sorry put filter value there