# Send data with Javascript function in Express response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to send an application/javascript response from my Express server, passing the data which I have got from MongoDB.

This is a response to a call for loading some  in a third party website.

I have created all the different parts of the process, now just need to pass on the data into the Javascript response.

server.js

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    productInfo(param1, param2, res)
}
```

productInfo.js - MongoDB call

```
function productInfo(param1, param2, res){

    Product.find({key1: param1}, (err, docs) => {
    let idList = docs.idList;

    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/script.js', (err) => {
       if (err) { console.log(err) }
       else { console.log('file sent') }
    });
}

module.exports = productInfo;
```

script.js - sending a self executing anonymous function

```
(function(){
    // function - load jQuery & Bootstrap in 3rd party website

    $masterDiv = $(`
    <div>
    ...
    ... *data required*
    </div>
    `)

    $('body').append($masterDiv);

    // function - jquery event handlers where *data is required*
})();
```

When some event happens on the third party website page, the event handlers update the right data (id).

How do I pass along data (idList) to script.js?

If I set dummy global variables data before the (function(){})(); line in script.js then I can access it within the function.

I tried res.render but it says "Cannot find module 'js'".

`res.render(__dirname + '/scriptproduct.js', (err) => {});`

1. Can I somehow set params to script.js function and call the function with res.send(functionName(idList))?
2. I have seen answers with templates being sent in html views with res.render but how do I use such a solution in my case where the data is required both in JS and HTML?
3. I have lots of other routes which are not using a template engine. Can I use it for just one route if that is the solution?

I am very new to all this and basically hacking forward to a solution. So some of my questions above might be elementary.

Answer (score 0):

Using ejs you can pass a string to a EJS template or a .js file. However, you can only pass strings. What you could do is pass the object as a string using JSON.stringify(obj) and then use JSON.parse(obj) to convert it back.

Here's another answer that has some code and may help: [How to include external .js file to ejs Node template page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001537/how-to-include-external-js-file-to-ejs-node-template-page?rq=1)