# Applying functions in .ejs templates

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

So I have the codes shown below and I am creating an app using Groom IDE (don't know if you have heard about it) I want to include JavaScript code shown below in ejs template and have no idea how to do that. I would appreciate any help from you

CSS code

```
nav{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3FA9A5;

}

.hide{
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: 'Long Cang', cursive;
    display: block;
}
.appear{
    height: 70px;
    display: none;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    transition: all 2s linear;

}

.appear img{
    width: 210px;

}
```

part of HTML code in ejs file

```
<nav class="hide">
    <ul>
        <li class="hide">Unknown</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<nav class="appear">
    <li><img url="../cat.png"></li>
</nav>
```

And here is JS code I want to apply

```
var hide = document.querySelector(".hide");
var appear = document.querySelector(".appear")

window.onscroll = function(){
    if(window.scrollY < 70){
        hide.style.display = "block";
        appear.style.display = "none"
    } else {
        hide.style.display = "none";
        appear.style.display = "block"
    }
}
```

this is how my express.js code looks like right now

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('main')
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
    console.log('Server is running!!')
})
```

Comment: Have you tried just inserting a normal `<script>` tag (as in normal html)? I've never heard of Groom IDE, and might be silly to ask, but at least with firebase functions (node environment) and handlebars used for templates, this is working.

Comment: Hi, I was thinking about it but did not try. I know I can include Js in ejs file using <% %> but don't know if it is good idea and how to do that. Maybe I should create another file with all js code

Comment: Actually I think you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001537/how-to-include-external-js-file-to-ejs-node-template-page)