# issues with implementing front end js code on view engine

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ejs

So I am currently working on this form validation part for this web-based app. Trying to apply some front end js code on the ejs file as shown below,

```
<body>
    <h1>Doctor</h1>
    <p>Registration</p>
    <!--physician route-->
    <div id="doc_reg">
        <form method='POST'onsubmit="return formValidation()"action="/physician/loggedin">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name">
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="user_email" name="user_email">
            <label>Type in First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name">
            <label>Type in Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name">
            <label>Create your password:</label>
            <input type="text" id='password_1' name='password_1'>
            <label>Confirm your password:</label>
            <input type="text" id='password_2' name='password_2'>
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="../../public/doclogin.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

the js code that I am trying to implement here (made it simple just for the sake of convenience in communication)

```
function formValidation(){
    const user_name = document.getElementById('user_name').value
    const user_email = document.getElementById('user_email').value
    const first_name = document.getElementById('first_name').value
    const last_name = document.getElementById('last_name').value
    const password_1 = document.getElementById('password_1').value
    const password_2 = document.getElementById('password_2').value

    //we will leave the creating password part later, because it is such a pain in the ass

    if (user_name==="" || user_email==="" || first_name==="" || last_name===""|| password_1===""|| password_2===""){
        alert("Information Missing for Required Entries")
        return false
    }
}
```

I don't know why the validation does not work the way it is expected. 
However, when I make a form on a **pure html file** with the same js code, it works. 
Why is that??

Answer (score 0):

use && to check for all required fields

Comment: I am pretty sure it is supposed to be 'or' relation between the inputs instead of 'and'. if you have say just one input field left empty and all others filled, the submission shall not go through

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question can be found here [How to include external .js file to ejs Node template page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001537/how-to-include-external-js-file-to-ejs-node-template-page).